# Luarocks error on ubuntu

Tags: torch, luarocks

I am trying to run Neuraltalk2 on Ubuntu. But I am getting an error as follows:

```
parag@parag:~/torch$ sudo luarocks install nn
[sudo] password for parag: 

Error: No results matching query were found.
```

I followed the following steps uptill now:

```
sudo curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/ezinstall/master/install-deps | bash
sudo git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
sudo cd ~/torch;
sudo ./install.sh
sudo source ~/.bashrc
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Try running this all without `sudo`. The last line, especially, `sudo source ~/.bashrc` does not work because `source` is meant to operate on the shell you are currently running. If you run it with `sudo`, it will load `.bashrc` into the temporary subshell created by `sudo` (in practice having no effect).

Your error message indicates that `luarocks` was installed correctly, but it failed to find the rock. Make sure the name of the rock is correct, try searching it with the `luarocks search` command, and check your configuration running `luarocks` with no arguments (it will display the name of your config files in use, helping you to troubleshoot the issue).